# computing kernel matrix without loops in R

Tags: r

I need to compute a kernel matrix for a large dataset. The function that I wrote contains double for loops and it gets very slow on large data. Is there any way I can avoid those. (Also I know there are many functions to compute kernels in R, but eventually I would like to design my own kernel and that would involve similar code so need to get some feedback on how to make it run faster). Here is my code with an example.

```
set.seed(130)

# generate multivariate data
M<-3
N<-15
datamat<-matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M) 
head(datamat)

# Function to compute Kernel
rbf = function(x,y,gamma=0.5) {
  Sigma <- matrix(rep(0, nrow(x)*nrow(y)), nrow=nrow(x),ncol=nrow(x))
   for (i in 1:nrow(Sigma)) {
   for (j in 1:ncol(Sigma)) {
    Sigma[i,j] <- exp(-gamma*(x[i,]-y[j,])%*%t(t(x[i,]-y[j,])))
    }
  }
  return(Sigma)
}


my.rbf<-rbf(datamat, datamat)

head(my.rbf)
```

Comment: Why not just look at the code of the other kernel functions. You could benchmark them, see which is faster and compare the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I looked at the identical post and but that method takes about the same time as double for loop so does not help.